# Special cases for angle between vectors formula

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given points $A(x_1,y_1)$, $B(x_2,y_2)$, $C(x_3,y_3)$, and $D(x_4,y_4)$, we can form vectors $\vec{AB}(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1)$ and $\vec{CD}(x_4-x_3,y_4-y_3)$. Then the cosine of an angle $\alpha$ between vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{CD}$ will be equal to:

$$
\cos\alpha = \dfrac{(x_2-x_1)(x_4-x_3) + (y_2-y_1)(y_4-y_3)}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}\sqrt{(x_4-x_3)^2+(y_4-y_3)^2}}
$$

Are there any special cases which would allow to simplify the calculation of this formula? I'm looking for a list of as many of these cases as possible.

Comment: What sort of special cases are you looking for? You can just translate to have the vectors start at the origin.

Comment: Depends on what kind of answer do you want.  
Angles are always preserved by translation, so you can always translate one of the points to the origin by a certain vector and perform the same translation to all points (it's an isometry).  
Now, when you need to measure an angle described by two vectors, you usually join them by a common point, so you can further assume a common point, and it is thus natural to choose this common point as $(0, 0)$.  
The formula would be simplified to the extent of only depending from 4 variables. So, due to the answer's simplicity, please ellaborate.

Comment: You could further simplify it by rotating them in such a way that one of the vectors is paralell to one of the axis, so that you could further annihilate another variable to $0$, ending up with a formula that depends on 3 variables.